# recursion with a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I just started learning python and there are some recursion questions that I can't seem to figure out. The most annoying one is this:
I need to build a function `ind(e,L)` where `e` is an int and `L` is a list.

By entering `e` if it is in the list the output needs to be its index
For example:

```
ind(42,[0,14,52,42,15]) -> 3
```

This is the code I wrote this far but the index I get is always 0. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
def location(e,L):
    if L == []:
        return False
    elif e == L[0]:
        A = L[:-1].index(e)
        return A
    else:
        return location(e,L[1:])

print(location(14,[1,2,14,1]))
```

thanks :)

Comment: First of all, if the goal of excercise is to learn recursion and implement location function on your own, why do you use . index (that is doing exactly what you want location to do) inside? And if the goal wasn't to implement it on your own, why don't you just use index?

Comment: And the only case when you finish recursion if the element is present, is when `e == L[0]`. So how can you expect something else than 0 being returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find index of element in a list using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481429/find-index-of-element-in-a-list-using-recursion)

Answer (score 2):

You only return if `e` is at index 0 (you can skip the `L[:-1]...` term, it is always 0) and propagate that unchanged. Instead of returning the meaningless index, return the number of recursions. The simplest way is to add 1 whenever the function recurses.

```
def location(element, sequence):
    if not sequence:
        # e is not in the list at all
        # it is not meaningful to return an index
        raise IndexError
    elif element == sequence[0]:
        # we already know where e is
        # since we checked it explicitly
        return 0
    else:
        # keep searching in the remainder,
        # but increment recursion level by 1
        return 1 + location(element, sequence[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new as well, but I think this should do the trick...

```
def function(e,L):
    try:
        x = 0
        for val in L:
            if e == val:
                return(x)
            else: x = x+1
    except:
        print('List provided does not contain any values')
```

x will count through the values and return when the index equals a value in the list. It will also return multiple matches, which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to notice is that `the time complexity` and `the space complexity` of your code is `O(n^2)`. Because `L[1:]` creates a `new list` every time! It is `O(n)` operation in terms of `time` and `space`.

---

One proper Pythonic way of doing it is:

```
def location(e, L):
    n = len(L)

    def _location(start):
        if start == n:
            raise IndexError

        if L[start] == e:
            return start

        return _location(start + 1)

    return _location(0)

print(location(14, [1, 2, 14, 1]))
```

Output:

```
2
```

---

Time Complexity: `O(n)`

Space Complexity: `O(n)` (Due to recursion.)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit different. I start looking for `e` from the right end of `L`. If found, then the index is simply the length of `L` minus 1 (since Python indexes start with 0).

This implementation does not require you to make any variable to store the index, which I think is neat.

```
def location(e, L):
    if L:
        if L[-1] == e:
            return len(L)-1
        else:
            return location(e, L[:-1])
    return False
```

Test:

```
>>> L = [0,14,52,42,15]
>>> location(42, L)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter recursive solution:

```
def ind(a, b):
   def _ind(a, b):
     return False if not b else (b[0] == a or 1+_ind(a, b[1:]))
   return _ind(a, b) - 1

print(ind(42,[0,14,52,42,15]))
```

Output:

```
3
```

If you do not mind offsetting by one:

```
def ind(a, b):
  return False if not b else (b[0] == a or 1+ind(a, b[1:]))

>>>ind(42,[0,14,52,42,15]) - 1
```

Or, using a default parameter:

```
def ind(a, b, c = 0):
   return False if not b else (c if b[0] == a else ind(a, b[1:], c+1))

>>>ind(42,[0,14,52,42,15])
```